# Vanilla NG2 component not displaying?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-components

So in my angular 2 app I have:

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { sidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<sidebar></sidebar>
  <h1>helps</h1>`,
  providers: [sidebarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and

```
//sidebar.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  template: `<h1>sidebar</h1>`
})
export class sidebarComponent { }
```

When I load my app and app.component is displayed, I get `<sidebar></sidebar><h1>helps</h1>` rendered directly (in the page source), but no `<h1>sidebar</h1>`. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What have I missed here?** Directives :-)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { sidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<sidebar></sidebar>
  <h1>helps</h1>`,
  directives: [sidebarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `directives:[sidebarComponent]` instead of `providers: [sidebarComponent]`